# FHIR: How to query DocumentReference by Encounter

Tags: hl7-fhir

How can I get a list of DocumentReference entries that reference a specific Encounter?

I expected this to work, but the list of results is not confined to the Encounter that I specified

Encounter:

```
<Encounter xmlns="http://hl7.org/fhir">
    <id value="ekI3ZxMnLW7V-.vMaXzPoMQ3" />
...
```

`GET: https://fhirServerUrl/DocumentReference?context=Encounter/ekI3ZxMnLW7V-.vMaXzPoMQ3`

Comment: What came back in the 'self' link in the SearchResponse?  Does your server support the 'context' SearchParameter?  Note that 'context' is defined in R5 and most servers only support FHIR R4.  You might try using 'encounter' instead - which exists in R4.

Comment: You should check the documentation for the FHIR server to see if they support the context search parameter.  Based on the FHIR ID you provided, I'm guessing you are looking at Epic's FHIR server, which doesn't support the context search param on DocRef.